# Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I stringify my canvas and load it from another canvas using loadFromJSON and I got this error "Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined"

What is wrong with this and how I will fix it?

Answer (score 6):

It's because you changed object [type](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#type) property of object while adding to canvas.

While loading from JSON it checks for type of object then it loads from respective class, that time you don't have a class having your modified object type. So `type` must be same as class name, or starting letter can be in lowerCase, not the rest.

> Ex: class name -- possible type
>
> fabric.Rect ---> type: rect / Rect
>
> fabric.Circle ---> type: circle / Circle
>
> fabric.CustomClass ---> type: customClass / CustomClass / Custom-Class / Custom-class / custom-class / custom-Class