# Can't read property 'fromObject' of undefined

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, next.js13

For the undo and redo functinality, I stringify my canvas and load it the previous canvas data using loadFromJSON and I got this error "Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined" when trying to load the JSON that contain arrow annotaion details
Arrow annotation code when drawing -

```
 if (isDrawing.arrow) {
            let pointer = editor.canvas.getPointer(event.e);
            let line, triangle, activeObj, deltaX, deltaY;
            const points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
            line = new fabric.Line(points, {
                strokeWidth: 6,
                fill: `${selectedColor}`,
                stroke: `${selectedColor}`,
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center',
                id: 'arrow_line',
                uuid: generateUUID(),
                type: 'arrow'
            });
            const centerX = (line.x1 + line.x2) / 2;
            const centerY = (line.y1 + line.y2) / 2;
            deltaX = line.left - centerX;
            deltaY = line.top - centerY;

            triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
                left: line.get('x1') + deltaX,
                top: line.get('y1') + deltaY,
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center',
                selectable: false,
                strokeWidth: 30,
                pointType: 'arrow_start',
                angle: -45,
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                fill: selectedColor,
                id: 'arrow_triangle',
                uuid: line.uuid
            });
            editor.canvas.add(line, triangle);
            activeObj = line;
            const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
                const pointer = editor.canvas.getPointer(event.e);
                line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
                triangle.set({
                    'left': pointer.x + deltaX,
                    'top': pointer.y + deltaY,
                    'angle': _FabricCalcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2),
                    'fill': `${selectedColor}`, // Set fill color for the line
                    'stroke': `${selectedColor}`, // Set stroke color for the line
                });
                line.set({
                    'fill': `${selectedColor}`, // Set fill color for the line
                    'stroke': `${selectedColor}`, // Set stroke color for the line
                });
                editor.canvas.renderAll();
            }
            const handleMouseUp = () => {
                const group = new window.fabric.Group([line, triangle],
                    {
                        borderColor: selectedColor,
                        cornerColor: 'green',
                        lockScalingFlip: true,
                        typeOfGroup: 'arrow',
                        userLevel: 1,
                        name: 'my_ArrowGroup',
                        uuid: activeObj.uuid,
                        type: 'arrow',
                        'fill': selectedColor,
                        'stroke': selectedColor
                    });
                editor.canvas.remove(line, triangle);// removing old object
                activeObj = group;
                editor.canvas.add(group);
                setIsDrawing({ ...isDrawing, arrow: false });
                setIsEditing({ ...isEditing, arrow: true });
                setSelectedShape(null);
                addToHistory({ type: 'added', object: group });
                updateModifications(true);
                editor.canvas.forEachObject((obj) => {
                    obj.selectable = true;
                });
            }
            editor.canvas.on("mouse:move", handleMouseMove);
            editor.canvas.on("mouse:up", handleMouseUp);
            return () => {
                editor.canvas.off("mouse:move", handleMouseMove);
                editor.canvas.off("mouse:up", handleMouseUp);
            };

        }`
```

and for loading the json data using -

```
 `editor.canvas.loadFromJSON(JsonString);`
```

here is the Json  -
`[{"type":"arrow","version":"5.3.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":468.34,"top":376.08,"width":2151.08,"height":1018.94,"fill":"primary.black","stroke":"primary.black","strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"objects":[{"type":"arrow","version":"5.3.0","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":-15.1,"top":-15.1,"width":2114.87,"height":982.74,"fill":"#E8D105","stroke":"#E8D105","strokeWidth":20,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"x1":-1057.437234445406,"x2":1057.437234445406,"y1":-491.36875040035187,"y2":491.36875040035187},{"type":"triangle","version":"5.3.0","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":1042.33,"top":476.27,"width":20,"height":20,"fill":"#E8D105","stroke":"#E8D105","strokeWidth":20,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":114.92,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0}]}],"backgroundImage":{"type":"image","version":"5.3.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":3840,"height":2160,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"sample.jpg","crossOrigin":null,"filters":[]}}'`

Here the link the i tried to resolve this issue
[Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837727/cannot-read-property-fromobject-of-undefined)
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4376
https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/314664-fabricjs-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-id-at-iupdatenewlinecoordinates/